# Use a variable for the subject parameter in the Rails mail_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Using the mail_to helper, is there a way to populate the subject parameter with a variable, such as page url, title, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, url is easy, title may be trickier depending on what you are using.

```
<%= mail_to "kirk@starfleet.edu", :subject => "URL: #{request.url}, Title: @page.title" %>
```

ian.